# Pycord - Roll a Dice Slash Command

Tags: python, discord, bots, pycord

I'm trying to make a Roll command where you either choose the upper limit or leave it default (6)
Here is what i tried:

```
@bot.slash_command(name="roll", description="Rolls a dice", guild_ids=[824342611774144543])
async def roll(ctx, upper_limit: Option(int, required=False)):

    d = random.randint(1, upper_limit)
    dd = random.randint(1, 6)

    if upper_limit == None:
        await ctx.respond(dd)
    else:
        await ctx.respond(d)
```

The command runs fine when i choose the upper limit, but when i leave it default it raises an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 768, in process_application_commands
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 306, in invoke
    await injected(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 116, in wrapped
    raise ApplicationCommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.commands.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't input an `upper_limit` it's set as `None`, so you are trying to get a random integer from 1 to `None` when defining your `d` variable, which generates this error you're getting.

To avoid this, you could do the following in the body of your command:

```
if upper_limit is None:
        dd = random.randint(1, 6)
        await ctx.respond(dd)
else:
        d = random.randint(1, upper_limit)
        await ctx.respond(d)
```

This way, it will only execute `d = random.randint(1, upper_limit)` when `upper_limit` is not `None`

Alternatively, you could give `upper_limit` a default value (6 in your case). So your command would look like this:

```
@bot.slash_command(name="roll", description="Rolls a dice", guild_ids=[824342611774144543])
async def roll(ctx, upper_limit: Option(int, required=False)=6):

    d = random.randint(1, upper_limit)
    await ctx.respond(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have upper_limit set to none by default, random cannot choose a random number between 1 and none; which is not an integer. This isn't the only solution, but you could append a simple `= default value` to your code like this:

```
async def roll(ctx, upper_limit: Option(int, required=False)=your default value here):
```